# Rails : ActiveRecord StatementInvalid Mysql2 Error Out of range value for column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need a way in rails 4 through which I can validate data in multiple models based on different type of column. I have an application which has several models each model has various columns. I need to validate each attribute value based on the type of column so that It will not generate

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column
```

I have `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` mode in mysql in my application. Previously `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` was set to `false` and now I had to set it to `true`. I need to validate decimal with different precision and scale (based on different model), string for value within string range of (255 character) and so on..
Previously I tried to handle it with exception handling in controller but that doesn't give validation failure for model.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, with: :statement_invalid
def statement_invalid(exception)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render json: { message: 'Not Found' }, status: 404 }
    format.json { render json: { message: 'Not Found' }, status: 404 }
    format.html { render 'shared/page_not_found', status: 404 }
  end
end
```

Comment: You want to add validations to your models? ActiveRecord has all kinds of support for that so why aren't you using it?

Comment: @muistooshort Actually I need to validate around 60 models as the project is quite big and we have upgraded from Rails 3 to 4, previously we didn't use MySQL strict mode and now we are using it, so I am searching if I can add this validation globally i.e., adding at one place validates all the model's attributes (overriding any ActiveRecord method or something like that). Searching for possibilities if there are any.